# Syncsort produces a non-readable output for decimal(9,8) or smallint data type columns in Db2

Tags: db2, mainframe, db2-zos, syncsort

I am using Syncsort to select records from Db2.  For the columns that are either decimal(9,8) or smallint the output looks weird with junk characters in it. If I cast the column to CHAR type in the select statement the output is proper.  I do not want to cast the column type to char in the SQL statement rather I want a solution in syncsort if this is possible.

For example: the decimal column has a value 2.98965467 which is displayed in a non-readable format by Syncsort if I don't use casting in the SQL statement.  Kindly help

Comment: display of binary data in a human-readable form will require a conversion.

Comment: Those junks does not look binary.

Comment: Will you pleaase edit your question and add the sort statemenst you use, as well as the definition of the DB2 table. Insert this as `code` so we can cut&paste if needed to help you.